# Restler always returns 404: Not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, restler

I have installed Restler on my local server to test and make some APIs for my project.

Api requests are handled via `http://localhost/myproject/api/`.

The problem is that everytime i try to make a request i get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    },
    "debug": {
        "source": "Routes.php:383 at route stage",
        "stages": {
            "success": [
                "get"
            ],
            "failure": [
                "route",
                "negotiate",
                "message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Also this is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api(.*)$ /myproject/api/api.php [QSA,L]
```

And this is what the `api.php` looks like:

```
namespace myproject;

use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myproject/resources/engine/settings.php");
require_once(Settings\Path\Absolute::$library."/restler/vendor/restler.php");

$restler = new Restler();
$restler->addAPIClass("myproject\\User");
$restler->handle();
```

I guess there's some misconfiguration around, but i really can't figure out what's wrong.

(I also tried some solutions on Stackoverflow but they doesn't seem to work for me)

**Edit:**

I tried reaching the example using the following path  `http://localhost/myproject/resources/engine/library/restler/public/examples` and they're working, so i guess it has to do with the configuration of Restler itself because it doesn't seem to work in `http://localhost/myproject/api`.

Furthermore i also tried copying the Restler Explorer in `http://localhost/myproject/api/explorer` and i keep receiving the error: `404 : Not Found ../resources.json` probably because i didn't install Restler in the root folder of my project. How am I supposed to install Restler in a different subfolder?

**Edit 2:**
I just moved the following class into the example 001 folder:

```
class User {

    function data() {

        return "HELLO!";
    }
}
```

and added this line inside the `index.php` of the example:

```
$r->addAPIClass('User');
```

If i try to run the example at `.../_001_helloworld/index.php/say/hello` it works without problems but if i try `_001_helloworld/index.php/user/data` it isn't.

At this point i have lost every hope and i really need help 'cause really i'm missing something but really can't guess what :( **HELP!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can debug and find whats wrong,

- Remove the namespace in api.php. It is not required and will cause issues.
- Copy explorer folder to `/myproject/api` folder and add Resources class as an api class

  ```
  $restler->addApiClass('Resources'); //this produces the needed resources.json
  ```
- If you are adding User class with a namespace, make sure it defined under that namespace and made available with your include statements or autoloader.
- You can create `/myproject/api/cache` folder and make it writable. When you instantiate restler in production mode with cache refresh as shown below, it will create routes.php in cache folder which lists all the routes information

  ```
  $restler = new Restler(true,true); //production_mode, refresh
  ```

Hope you find whats wrong with the above

Comment: I followed the first 2 steps and that solved the problem. Thank you, i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. It was all working yesterday, then I started receiving the 404 message from Restler. None of my web server configuration has changed.

Going via index.php works, and going that way or without index.php creates a routes.php file that is identical in both cases.

Comment: Please ignore my comment; I was using the wrong URL.. Doh

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your function is `public` not `private`.

I actually just had the same problem and just spent an hour figuring it out (facepalm).