# Luracast restler 404: Not Found ../resources.json

Tags: php, json, apache, restler

Good night!
I'm trying to use the restler, yet sempe have the same problem:
404: Not Found ../resources.json

This is my .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /api/explorer
    RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

I've tried already do:

change the httpd.conf and put:

```
 AllowOverride All
 Options FollowSymLinks
```

follow several suggestions given by similar preguntas here.
tried to do what is suggested here

[Restler always returns 404: Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488815/restler-always-returns-404-not-found)

copy the folder explorer for api folder ...
But none of this works, please tell me what can I be doing wrong?
Is it to be using wamp?

edited:
here is the addiction of resources class

```
<?php
require '../../bootstrap.php';

use Luracast\Restler;
use TDI2014\Resource;

$r = new Restler\Restler();
$r->addAPIClass(Resource\Student::class);
$r->addAPIClass('Resources');
$r->handle();
```

here's a print of my page
[image]

this is my json response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    },
    "debug": {
        "source": "Routes.php:436 at route stage",
        "stages": {
            "success": [
                "get"
            ],
            "failure": [
                "route",
                "negotiate",
                "message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `Resources` as an Api class? The 404 response you are getting, does that include a json response?

Comment: First I apologize for not being the answer now , but I've been without internet connection .
Yes I added the class, so I have : ( edited the question because I can not put code here )